# How to serve a non-ASCII file name with Django and Apache using xsendfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, x-sendfile

I wanted to serve protected contents in Django, so I tried to set **xsendfile** in both Django and Apache. It works for ASCII file names, but when I tried with non-ASCII file name the Apache server responds with 404. What’s going on here?

#### Django:

```
def media_xsendfile_pdf(request):
    file = Media.objects.last()
    response = HttpResponse()
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(f"{settings.BASE_DIR}{file.file.url}")
    return response
```

#### Apache:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
XSendFile On
XsendFilePath /path-to-the-protected-resource
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution for this. In the response header, we need set the **X-sendfile** like below:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
response["X-sendfile"] = unquote(<url>).encode('utf-8')
```